# How to add user input values to an array in Ocaml

Tags: ocaml

I am working in OCaml and have to do the following problem

```
7.1 Problem 1 – Number of values less than average
Input: An integer, listlen, followed by listlen number of integer values.
Output: The list of values, number of items on the list, and the number of input values that are less than the average of all the values
Sample input:
Enter the count and the corresponding integer values:
7 10 60 3 55 15 45 40
Corresponding output:
The list:
10 60 3 55 15 45 40
The average:
32.57
Number of values less than average:
3
```

The idea is to use user input, get a length of numbers to be averaged, get the numbers to be averaged, average them and then tell which numbers from the list are less than the average. My issue comes in trying to add the values given from the user into the array. I was able to create the array but can't figure out what code to use to add the values.

The code I have currently...

```
(* Prompts the user to enter the number of values they want to average
then gets that number and prints it *)
print_string "Enter The Number of Values You Want To Average:\n";;
let n_values = Scanf.scanf "%d" (fun n -> n);;
Printf.printf "%d\n" n_values;;

(* Prompts the user to enter the numbers they want averaged then
adds those values to an array and prints the numbers *)
print_string "Enter The Values To Be Averaged:\n";;
let a = Array.make n_values 0;;

for i = 0 to Array.length a - 1 do
    (*let values = Scanf.scanf "%d" (fun n -> n)*)
    a.(i) <- i
  done;;

for i = 0 to Array.length a - 1 do
    Printf.printf "%i" a.(i);
done;;

(* Adds each of the values of the array together, stores it in sum and then divides by the n_values initialized above and stores in average, then prints this value *)
print_string "\nThe Average:\n";;
let sum = Array.fold_left (+) 0 a;;
let average = sum / n_values;;
Printf.printf "%d\n" average;;

(* Checks which numbers in the array are less than the computed average and increments a counter if it is less*)
print_string "The Number of Values Less Than The Average:\n";;
let counter = ref 0;;
for i = 0 to Array.length a - 1 do
   if a.(i) < average then incr counter;
done;;
Printf.printf "%d\n" !counter;;
```

The code in question is...

```
let a = Array.make n_values 0;;

for i = 0 to Array.length a - 1 do
    (*let values = Scanf.scanf "%d" (fun n -> n)*)
    a.(i) <- i
  done;;

for i = 0 to Array.length a - 1 do
    Printf.printf "%i" a.(i);
done;;
```

I have tried what is currently commented out w/ adding `a.(i) <- values` but that did not work and it gave me an error of 
`Fatal error: exception Scanf.Scan_failure("scanf: bad input at char number 1: character ' ' is not a decimal digit")`

Answer (score 1):

If you include the commented out code you have this:

```
let values = Scanf.scanf "%d" (fun n -> n)
a.(i) <- i
```

This isn't syntactically valid because it has a `let` with no `in`. Your description of the problem isn't specific enough to tell whether that was your problem. If so, you need add `in` after the right parenthesis in the first line.

If this wasn't your problem, you might note that the second line of code here doesn't use `values` even though that's pretty much what I would expect it to do. The code as it stands reads a value from stdin, then ignores the value that it read.

If neither of these is your problem, you need to describe your problem more carefully. It's difficult to help if all you say is "it did not work."

Comment: I meant to say that if I used the commented out code I would have done `a.(i) <- values`

Comment: so I ran the code like this `let a = Array.make n_values 0;;

for i = 0 to Array.length a - 1 do
    let values = Scanf.scanf "%d" (fun n -> n) in
    a.(i) <- values;
  done;;
  
for i = 0 to Array.length a - 1 do
    Printf.printf "%i" a.(i);
done;;` and I got the error `Fatal error: exception Scanf.Scan_failure("scanf: bad input at char number 1: character ' ' is not a decimal digit")`

Answer (score 0):

A further suggestion to the correct answer Jeffrey Scofield has provided: use [`Array.init`](https://v2.ocaml.org/api/Array.html#VALinit) to avoid creating the array and then looping over its indices to assign values to it.

```
# Array.init 10 @@ fun _ -> Scanf.scanf " %d" Fun.id;;
56
7
2
4
56
87
90
12
12
56
- : int array = [|56; 7; 2; 4; 56; 87; 90; 12; 12; 56|]
```